# Ruby 2.1.3 crashes when Working with libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Specs:
- Ruby version `2.1.3p242`
- MySQL version `0.3.16`
- Rails version `4.1.6`
- Rake version `10.3.2`

I was attempting to run `rake db` for the first time.  The `database.yml` file is properly configured, because it is working on our other machines.  We're filing a bug report with the Ruby-lang; however, we hope somebody can point out a workaround.

When dragging the `libmysql.dll` file into `C:\Ruby{...}\bin` results in the following crash:

```

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x64-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0027 p:-10024584 s:0097 e:000096 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0026 p:---- s:0095 e:000094 CFUNC  :require
c:0025 p:0083 s:0091 e:000090 TOP    C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0024 p:---- s:0089 e:000088 CFUNC  :require
c:0023 p:0037 s:0085 e:000084 BLOCK  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0022 p:---- s:0082 e:000081 CFUNC  :each
c:0021 p:0055 s:0079 e:000078 BLOCK  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0072 e:000071 CFUNC  :each
c:0019 p:0030 s:0069 e:000068 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
c:0018 p:0013 s:0065 e:000064 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133
c:0017 p:0047 s:0061 e:000060 TOP    C:/Users/KayteaQ/Documents/GitHub/FacultyRepublic/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0016 p:---- s:0059 e:000058 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0115 s:0055 e:000054 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0014 p:0018 s:0045 e:000044 TOP    C:/Users/KayteaQ/Documents/GitHub/FacultyRepublic/Rakefile:4 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0043 e:000042 CFUNC  :load
c:0012 p:0009 s:0039 e:000038 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28
c:0011 p:0176 s:0035 e:000034 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687
c:0010 p:0007 s:0030 e:000029 BLOCK  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94
c:0009 p:0006 s:0028 e:000027 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176
c:0008 p:0007 s:0024 e:000023 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93
c:0007 p:0013 s:0021 e:000020 BLOCK  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77
c:0006 p:0006 s:0019 e:000018 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176
c:0005 p:0007 s:0015 e:000014 METHOD C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75
c:0004 p:0040 s:0012 e:000011 TOP    C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0010 e:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0135 s:0006 E:0010c8 EVAL   C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/rake:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000f78 TOP    [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/Users/KayteaQ/Documents/GitHub/FacultyRepublic/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/Users/KayteaQ/Documents/GitHub/FacultyRepublic/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa) [0x00000000772B12FA]
C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9c) [0x000007FEFD3A10DC]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0xa4) [0x000000006B417174]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_name_err_mesg_new+0x841) [0x000000006B2C9851]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_bug+0x45) [0x000000006B2CA595]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_check_safe_str+0x351) [0x000000006B398D91]
 [0x0000000000401A85]
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(_C_specific_handler+0x9c) [0x00000000772785C8]
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlDecodePointer+0xad) [0x0000000077289D2D]
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlUnwindEx+0xbbf) [0x00000000772791CF]
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x2e) [0x00000000772B1248]
C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\extensions\x64-mingw32\2.1.0\mysql2-0.3.16\mysql2\mysql2.so(Init_mysql2+0x1e38) [0x00000000005A6198]
 [0x00000000005A343D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\extensions\x64-mingw32\2.1.0\mysql2-0.3.16\mysql2\mysql2.so(Init_mysql2+0x5a) [0x00000000005A43BA]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(dln_load+0x1d6) [0x000000006B281646]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_call_cfunc+0x130) [0x000000006B414110]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_require_safe+0x56f) [0x000000006B2D55DF]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_error_arity+0x1c6) [0x000000006B4021F6]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_f_send+0x5c1) [0x000000006B40CF91]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x1628) [0x000000006B406A18]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x5a5d) [0x000000006B40AE4D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_iseq_eval+0x183) [0x000000006B413A33]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_rubylevel_errinfo+0x66c) [0x000000006B2D39BC]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_require_safe+0x5a9) [0x000000006B2D5619]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_error_arity+0x1c6) [0x000000006B4021F6]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x1628) [0x000000006B406A18]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x5a5d) [0x000000006B40AE4D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_funcall+0x413) [0x000000006B40BF43]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_yield+0x74) [0x000000006B4132E4]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_ary_each+0x51) [0x000000006B281971]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_error_arity+0x1c6) [0x000000006B4021F6]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x1f71) [0x000000006B407361]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x5a5d) [0x000000006B40AE4D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_funcall+0x413) [0x000000006B40BF43]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_yield+0x74) [0x000000006B4132E4]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_ary_each+0x51) [0x000000006B281971]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_error_arity+0x1c6) [0x000000006B4021F6]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_f_send+0x5c1) [0x000000006B40CF91]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x1f71) [0x000000006B407361]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x5a5d) [0x000000006B40AE4D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_iseq_eval+0x183) [0x000000006B413A33]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_rubylevel_errinfo+0x66c) [0x000000006B2D39BC]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_require_safe+0x5a9) [0x000000006B2D5619]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_error_arity+0x1c6) [0x000000006B4021F6]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x1628) [0x000000006B406A18]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x5a5d) [0x000000006B40AE4D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_iseq_eval+0x183) [0x000000006B413A33]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_rubylevel_errinfo+0x66c) [0x000000006B2D39BC]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_rubylevel_errinfo+0x1147) [0x000000006B2D4497]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_error_arity+0x1c6) [0x000000006B4021F6]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_f_send+0x5c1) [0x000000006B40CF91]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x1628) [0x000000006B406A18]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x5a5d) [0x000000006B40AE4D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_iseq_eval+0x183) [0x000000006B413A33]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_rubylevel_errinfo+0x66c) [0x000000006B2D39BC]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_rubylevel_errinfo+0x1147) [0x000000006B2D4497]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_error_arity+0x1c6) [0x000000006B4021F6]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_f_send+0x5c1) [0x000000006B40CF91]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x1628) [0x000000006B406A18]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_localjump_error+0x5a5d) [0x000000006B40AE4D]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_iseq_eval_main+0x1d0) [0x000000006B413C50]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_check_copyable+0x304a) [0x000000006B2CF36A]
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby210.dll(ruby_run_node+0x51) [0x000000006B2D2281]
 [0x0000000000402D14]
 [0x00000000004013D7]
 [0x00000000004014F8]
C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll(BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd) [0x00000000771559ED]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/rake

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/enc/encdb.so
    2 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    3 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so
    4 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/rbconfig.rb
    5 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    6 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    7 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    8 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    9 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/version.rb
   10 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   11 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   12 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   13 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   14 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
   15 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   16 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   17 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
   18 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   19 thread.rb
   20 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/thread.so
   21 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb
   22 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   23 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
   24 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   25 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   26 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/version.rb
   27 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x64-mingw32/etc.so
   28 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb
   29 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/singleton.rb
   30 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb
   31 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/ostruct.rb
   32 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb
   33 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/ext/core.rb
   34 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/ext/string.rb
   35 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb
   36 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/ext/time.rb
   37 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb
   38 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/win32.rb
   39 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/linked_list.rb
   40 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb
   41 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/cpu_counter.rb
   42 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/scope.rb
   43 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_argument_error.rb
   44 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rule_recursion_overflow_error.rb
   45 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/shellwords.rb
   46 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb
   47 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/cloneable.rb
   48 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb
   49 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb
   50 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/pathmap.rb
   51 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb
   52 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/set.rb
   53 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/promise.rb
   54 C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/thread_pool.rb
```